# Where is Axiom of Choice used in the proof of Riesz and/or Hahn-Banach extension theorems?

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I read the proof of the Hahn-Banach extention theorem on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Riesz_extension_theorem#Connection_to_the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) and see no mention of the axiom of choice. The proof goes by constructing an appropriate convex cone and then invoking the Riesz extension theorem, whose [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Riesz_extension_theorem#Proof) is based on transfinite induction. However, I've heard several times that proving the Hahn-Banach extension theorem (for topological vector spaces) requires AC or some slightly weaker version (ultrafitrations). I conclude that if the proofs on wikipedia are correct, then there must be a disguised use of AC somewhere (in Riesz of Hahn-Banach extension theorem).

## Question

So, where is AC used in the proof of the Riesz or Hahn-Banach extension theorems ?

Comment: Hint: try spelling out the induction argument.  In particular, transfinite induction works on **ordinals**...

Comment: I think this question is better for Math.SE.

Comment: In Solovay's model the dual space of $\ell^\infty$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$ by the usual pairing. From this it follows that $\ell^\infty/c_0$ is a Banach space whose only continuous linear functional is $0$, and so the Hahn-Banach theorem is not true. Therefore not only is Hahn-Banach not provable from ZF, it is not provable from the axiom of dependent choice.

Comment: Solovay and Pincus also constructed a model of ZF + DC in which the Hahn-Banach theorem holds, but there are no non-principal ultrafilters, so the ultrafilter lemma implies the Hahn-Banach theorem, but not the other way.

Comment: Each step of the transfinite induction proof of Riesz's theorem (at the Wikipedia page you linked to) begins by **choosing** a point $z$ not yet in the domain of the functional being constructed.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. Indeed transfinite induction won't work on cardinals in general, so one needs either quotient space be finite-dimensional, otherwise one needs an AC-type assumption.